# need help in C programing about values of special character constants

Tags: c

Can anyone show me how to write a C program which prints the numerical value of the special character constants such as \n, \t, \v, \b, etc. by using them as string literals within printf() statements. This is my first semester of this major and I didnt have any experience about this before. please help me. Thanks alot!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack overflow is no training site for programming. Get a C book and learn.

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
printf("%d", '\t');
```

for example, which prints

```
9
```

In this example, the apparent `char` type is actually defining an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to print the values of 'normal' characters? If so, printing the special characters would work the same.

For instance, printing `"A\tB\n"` would result in `65 9 66 10` if you just process the characters in the string one by one. The escaping is merely done so you can use these special characters in a string in source code. As soon as the code is compiled, the characters are un-escaped.